# Maximum expected return portfolio: Lagrangean derivation of closed-form analytical solution

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, expected-return, portfolio-selection, derivation

\begin{align}
\arg \min_w \enspace & -w^\top \mu \\
\mathrm{s.t.} \enspace & 1_N^\top w = 1 \\
& w_i \geq 0 \enspace \forall i=1,\dots, N
\end{align}

is the optimization problem for solving the maximum expected return portfolio's weight vector $w$, where $\mu$ is the vector of asset expected returns, and the two constraints ensure the weights sum to 1 and are non-negative (the constrained no short-sales portfolio).

The Lagrangean of the above is

$$ L(w,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = -w^\top \mu - \lambda_1( 1_N^\top w - 1)- \lambda_2(?)$$
where the $\lambda$s are the Lagrangean multipliers.

How can I take the first order conditions (derivatives) of the Lagrangean $L$ to get the closed-form analytical solution of $w$?

Comment: Looks like you are _minimizing_ returns. Could be bad for one's career. Also your problem has unbounded solution unless you add _e.g._ a positivity condition to the $w$.

Comment: thanks for the correction. and yes it's the unconstrained portfolio, although we can get to the short-sale constrained portfolio as well

Comment: In the 2 asset case if $\mu = [0.1, 0]$ one can take $w = [x, 1-x]$ and take $x\to\infty$. Even if you allow short sales, the problem seems ill-posed.

Comment: how about multivariate, via lagrangean

Comment: Just add more zeros to the $\mu$ above. The problem does not go away.

Comment: @steveo'america is of course perfectly right. You are posing a linear optimization problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) and you will need more constraints (e.g. non-negativity) to arrive at non-degenerate results. Nevertheless, the optimal investment will simply be: "Pick the investment with the highest expected return." If you restrict to, say, "maximum 10% per asset", then the result will be "invest in a kind of waterfall from highest to lowest expected return until fully invested."

Comment: to get past non-degenerate results, I changed the question to the constrained no-short sales portfolio. not sure how the Lagrangean term is though for the non-negativity constraint

Comment: Hi, the augmented problem is *still* simply solved by the "waterfall" method I suggested above...

Comment: With the added positivity constraint, the second Lagrange multiplier becomes a _vector_. In this case the first order necessary conditions for the solution can not be used to derive a closed form solution. Rather you have to use LP solver, or follow @Kermittfrog 's recipe.

Comment: oh so unconstrained or constrained, the max return portfolio never had an analytical solution in the first place, ok